# Exercise from Williams book Probability with martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

I'm doing this exercise from Williams book Probability with martingales

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of IID random variables with $E(|X_n|) = \infty $ for all $n$. Then prove that $$1)\  \sum_n P(|X_n| > kn) = \infty \ \ k \in \mathbb{N}$$ $$2)\  \limsup_n \frac{|X_n|}{n} = \infty \ \ a.e. $$ $$3) \ \limsup_n \frac{|S_n|}{n} = \infty \ \ a.e. $$ where $S_n = X_1+ \ldots + X_n$.

I'm stuck with the point $3$, how to proceed ?

Comment: I suppose you either assume $X_n \geq 0$ or $\mathbb{E}(X^{-}_n) < \infty$? ($X_n^-$ denotes the negative part of $X_n$.)

Comment: @saz: I edited, it was $E(|X_n|) = \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n(\omega)|}{n}<\infty$$

for some $\omega \in \Omega$. Then

$$X_n = S_n-S_{n-1}$$

implies

$$\begin{align*} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|X_n(\omega)|}{n} &\leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n(\omega)|}{n} + \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_{n-1}(\omega)|}{n} \\ &= \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|S_n(\omega)|}{n} + \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{|S_{n-1}(\omega)|}{n-1} < \infty. \end{align*}$$

Now the claim follows from 2).